# How to direct devices by hacking a router changing the DNS settings?

Tags: dns, router

If I hacked a router's admin panel outside my network, is it possible to direct all devices in that network to any website I want by DNS settings? If it is possible, how?

Comment: Although your context is hacking, this is more of a DNS basics question than a security question. Do you know how DNS works?

Comment: i haven't much experience about networks but i want to know if it is possible to do somthing like that?

Answer (score 2):

If:

- the devices have not cached the IP of the domain locally
- the devices are configured to use the router for DNS
- the devices can access the website you want them to go to
- the original site (Facebook, Google, a bank, etc.) does not use TLS settings that prevent this sort of tampering
- the router allows you to edit the DNS table to enter your own settings
- the router does not override your new entries from authoritative entries from another DNS server

Then maybe.

As for how, you just create DNS entries.